# Get Authorization Token from PayPal

Tags: curl, paypal

This seems very simple, but I can't get around some authorization issues and keep getting errors. Im running this from OSX terminal. I have created the Rest API app from here https://developer.paypal.com/developer/applications with no obvious issues

from terminal:

```
curl -v https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token \
-H "Accept: application/json" \
-H "Accept-Language: en_US" \
-u "MyClientID:MyClientSecret" \
-d "grant_type=client_credentials"
```

I get this weird error back in terminal - {"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"Client Authentication failed"}NinjNNNNNiNiNiNinNinNiNinjNiNinNinjNiNiNiNinNiNinNinNNinNNinNiNiNinNNiNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNiNNNNNNNNNNNNiNNNNN

Anyone know the trick to this? The documentation is crazy, there are seemingly several apps that do the same thing, none of the documentation is making any sense. I want to take payments on my site, without leaving my site. Payflow seemed like the answer, are there any good tutorials out there?

Comment: The API expects an authorization token in the  `-u=` flag via  your curl request,  not your `clientid: secretkey` .See [How do I get an Access Token?] (https://www.paypal.com/us/smarthelp/article/how-do-i-get-an-access-token-ts2128)

Comment: Im trying to get the authorization token. Take a look at step 1 in the link you provided "Make a /token call with your app’s OAuth client_id and secret keys for the basic authentication values."